# Webpack: Typescript To Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, webpack-2

Ok, So I have beening playing around with learning Angular 2 with TypeScript. I am not a big fan of module loaders, so I thought I would give Webpack a go at building a bundle file, one for Angular 2 code and the other for my code.

However the problem with that is the file size for the vendor file, over 3mb - like 3.76mb :( - So I move over to using System JS, which could be the better option over all. But I still need to convert my Typescript files into ES5 / ES6 .js files, so I am trying to use Webpack (version 2) to do that but nothing I have read explains on how to do that?

If I am not building a bundle, would I be better using Grunt or something like that?

All help most welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at Webpack Dlls. Yes, it will not make your vendor bundle any smaller, but it will speed it dramatically your build time since it will require you the build the vendor part only once (at the beginning).

Comment: Thanks I might do that, but the main issue here is just to get a module loader (System JS) working. But before I can even start that I need to do a simple convert from Typescript to Javascipt. Now I can use Typesscipts TSC CLI option but I want that to be controlled by webpack

Comment: If you are using Angular 2, you really need to be building with angular-cli and Webpack. SystemJS is simpler than WebPack but not better. Whether you use Webpack (as in angular-cli) or SystemJS, the typescript is automatically going to be converted for you. You won't need to be worrying about that. If you were converting something manually for some reason, you would use Babel.

Comment: I am sorry but that can not be right, nothing I have seen about System JS loads a .ts file, its always a standard .js file! So how can it do that automatically? Plus I really dont want to use the angular-cli - maybe at some point I will, but I want to be able to do it without using a cli tool, so I know how its done.